# ireport working in local system using java code the same report showing an error in server instance

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports

I have bee created an report using the Ireport 4.1.1 application in my local system and defining the file paths where i have created as shown.

```
String jrxmlFileName = "/opt/OpenbravoERP/Reports/FacultyAttndDepartment.jrxml";

String jasperFileName = "/opt/OpenbravoERP/Reports/FacultyAttndDepartment.jasper";
```

When the same report I am running in the server instance using the related report libraries and some java code to generate an report in PDF file showing an error as shown.

The below are the libraries what I have used to create an report.

```
 package org.astute.reports;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
```

The error showing when i am running the report in server instance is,

HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception
type Exception report

message Servlet execution threw an exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:124)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:457)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:864)
>       org.astute.aits.hodportal.AllFacultyJasperServlet.doGet(AllFacultyJasperServlet.java:60)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

root cause

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.setTtf(SimpleFontFace.java:182)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFace(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:368)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamily(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:290)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.parseFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:254)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:215)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:184)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:56)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:110)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:124)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:89)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:104)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:62)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:81)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:457)
>       net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:864)
>       org.astute.aits.hodportal.AllFacultyJasperServlet.doGet(AllFacultyJasperServlet.java:60)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)

Comment: `JRRuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data` - that's the crucial part of information. Somewhere in your code, or in the report definition, a font (or font file) is specified, that is not available on the server.

Comment: But the same report is working in another sever with the same libraries what i used.Just i am doing the total dump into another server. Please can i have any clear explanation  what need to change where to change the modifications.

Comment: In report the font i am using is SansSerif and i have tried changing the font also in report level.Showing the same error.